# Is there something equivalent to template_preprocess_search_results()?

Tags: 8, search, theming

I just realized that template_preprocess_search_results() function has been left out in Drupal 8 for some reasons, although `template_preprocess_search_result()` (for single results) is still there.

I need to be able to manipulate the search results prior to rendering as I would with `template_preprocess_search_results()` in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that builds the search results is [`SearchController::view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Controller%21SearchController.php/function/SearchController%3A%3Aview/8.1.x), which contains the following code.

```
  $results = array();
  if ($request->query->has('keys')) {
    if ($plugin->isSearchExecutable()) {
      // Log the search.
      if ($this->config('search.settings')->get('logging')) {
        $this->logger->notice('Searched %type for %keys.', array('%keys' => $keys, '%type' => $entity->label()));
      }

      // Collect the search results.
      $results = $plugin->buildResults();
    }
    else {
      // The search not being executable means that no keywords or other
      // conditions were entered.
      drupal_set_message($this->t('Please enter some keywords.'), 'error');
    }
  }

  if (count($results)) {
    $build['search_results_title'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<h2>' . $this->t('Search results') . '</h2>',
    );
  }

  $build['search_results'] = array(
    '#theme' => array('item_list__search_results__' . $plugin->getPluginId(), 'item_list__search_results'),
    '#items' => $results,
    '#empty' => array(
      '#markup' => '<h3>' . $this->t('Your search yielded no results.') . '</h3>',
    ),
    '#list_type' => 'ol',
    '#context' => array(
      'plugin' => $plugin->getPluginId(),
    ),
  );
```

So, you can use `template_preprocess_item_list(&$variables)`, checking that `$variables['#context']['plugin']` is set. (I am not sure about using `template_preprocess_item_list__search_results(&$variables)`, since I have never tried using such preprocess function.)

The [`$plugin->buildResults()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Plugin%21SearchPluginBase.php/function/SearchPluginBase%3A%3AbuildResults/8.1.x) method called from `SearchController::view()` just builds the results as array of items themed with [search_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21templates%21search-result.html.twig/8.1.x).

```
  $results = $this->execute();

  $built = array();
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $built[] = array(
      '#theme' => 'search_result',
      '#result' => $result,
      '#plugin_id' => $this->getPluginId(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: template_preprocess_item_list__search_results() should work now in Drupal 8 *if* you actually have such a template.

Comment: That would make things easier, since the template would surely be used for the search result page.

Comment: @Berdir I did not find the function in the core docs so I just presumed it was removed. Can you please elaborate on the "if you have such a template"? Thanks!

Comment: @Henkealg Berdir was replying to my _I am not sure about using `template_preprocess_item_list__search_results(&$variables)` since I have never tried using such preprocess function._ He means you can use `template_preprocess_item_list__search_results(&$variables)` as long as you have a item_list__search_results.html.twig template.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I was able to use template_preprocess_item_list__search_results() in the way you suggested even though it is not included in the documentation anymore (strange). Kiam; I will mark your answer as accepted to close this thread. Thanks again.

Comment: @Henkealg You find [`template_preprocess_item_list()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_item_list/8.1.x); `template_preprocess_item_list__search_results()` is considered a variant of that preprocess function, and as such it is not documented.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new module and inside your YOUR_MODULE.module file put this code:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_item_list__search_results(&$variables) {
  //to use dpm() you nedd the devel module
  dpm($variables['items']);
}
```

Install your module and you will see the output in the search result